# Event Function's value in wxpython 4.01 / Python 3.7

Tags: events, combobox, wxpython

Sorry for my foolish...
so I upload full code

please teach me the right way....

at combobox i select one contents 
and it binded to   function "def OnSelectComboBox(self,event):"
and I want to get combobox's selected contents at 
*****"I want get the selected combobox contents here"***** position 
but I can't

so please teach me is it impossible or another way

thanks

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-



import wx 
import sqlite3 


from PIL import Image # for image processing
from wx.adv import Animation, AnimationCtrl # for gif Animation


conn = sqlite3.connect('reference_file.rre')
cur = conn.cursor()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):


        self.frame = errorCode_SAC(None, title ="Guide") 
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True


class errorCode_SAC(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Search", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(1500,650), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, name=""):
        super(errorCode_SAC, self).__init__(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name="")

        self.Panel_err_sac = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY, pos=(0,0), size=(774, 608)) 

        self.Panel_dd = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(777,0), size=(1,608))

        self.Panel_err_sac_result = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY, pos=(778,0), size=(706, 308)) 
        self.Panel_err_image = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY, pos=(778,309), size=(706,300)) 

        self.explBox_err_sac = wx.StaticBox(self.Panel_err_sac, wx.ID_ANY, "[ Instruction ]", pos = (8,10), size=(756, 200))

        self.lbname1 = wx.StaticText(self.explBox_err_sac, label="1.input name.",pos=(10,20))



        self.sa_ra_code_box = wx.StaticBox(self.Panel_err_sac, wx.ID_ANY, "[ input model ]", pos=(8,230), size=(340,80))

        self.sa_err_code_CeNa = wx.TextCtrl(self.sa_ra_code_box, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(8,30), size=(260,22))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.sa_ra_code_box, wx.ID_OK, label="search", size=(50,23), pos = (280,30))
        self.button.SetDefault()




        self.sa_er_Box = wx.StaticBox(self.Panel_err_sac, wx.ID_ANY, "[ Search by input name ]", pos = (8,320), size = (340,280))
        self.sa_er_inputkw = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_Box, label="",pos=(8,15), size=(10,40), style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.sa_er_middle = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_Box, label=" by", pos=(50,15))
        self.sa_er_middle = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_Box, label="", pos=(8,30))
        self.sa_er_footer = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_Box, label=" searched",pos=(50,30))




        self.sa_er_svlist = wx.ListCtrl(self.sa_er_Box, -1, pos = (8,60), size = (330,200), style = wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.sa_er_svlist.InsertColumn(0,"model")
        self.sa_er_svlist.InsertColumn(1,"spec")
        self.sa_er_svlist.SetColumnWidth(0,100)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.sa_err_catelist_OnClick, self.sa_er_svlist)         
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.sa_err_search_OnButton) 





        self.sa_er_result_Box = wx.StaticBox(self.Panel_err_sac, wx.ID_ANY, "[ check list ]", pos=(360,230), size =(405,370)) 
        self.sa_er_question_ti = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_result_Box, label="", pos=(50,20), size = (130,-1))


        self.sa_er_question_text = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_result_Box, label="point", pos = (10,50), size = (130,-1))                                    
        self.sa_er_question_te = wx.StaticText(self.sa_er_result_Box, label="", pos=(50,50), size = (130,-1)) 



        self.P_err_sac_case1 = wx.StaticBox(self.Panel_err_sac_result, wx.ID_ANY, "[ check list below ]", pos = (8,10), size=(690,60))
        self.P_err_sac_case2 = wx.StaticBox(self.Panel_err_sac_result, wx.ID_ANY, "[ symptom ]", pos=(8,90), size =(690,200))

        self.cas2_symp = wx.StaticText(self.P_err_sac_case2, label="selected symptom is..", pos=(10,20))
        self.cas2_symp_text = wx.StaticText(self.P_err_sac_case2, label="", pos=(10,40))

        self.cas2_descrip = wx.StaticText(self.P_err_sac_case2, label="cause....", pos=(10,70))
        self.cas2_descrip_text = wx.StaticText(self.P_err_sac_case2, label="", pos=(10,90)) 



    # -- Combo box 
        items=[] # Dummy list
        self.cb = wx.ComboBox(self.P_err_sac_case1, pos=(10,30),size=(500,20), choices=items, style=wx.CB_READONLY) 
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnSelectComboBox) 

    *****"I want get the selected combobox contents here"*****


# -- search query

    def sa_err_search_OnButton(self, e): 

        self.sa_er_inputkw.SetLabel(self.sa_err_code_CeNa.GetValue())
        searchResult = "%"+self.sa_err_code_CeNa.GetValue()+"%"
        self.sa_er_svlist.DeleteAllItems()


        sa_err_code_CeNa = cur.execute("Select * from sa_er_cate where cate like '"+searchResult+"'")

        count = 0

        for i in sa_err_code_CeNa:
            self.sa_er_svlist.Append(i[1:3])
            count = count +1
            self.sa_er_middle.SetLabel(str(count))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

    def on_close(self,e):
        self.Destroy()



    def sa_err_catelist_OnClick(self, event):

        sa_idx = event.GetIndex()
        sa_err_check = self.sa_er_svlist.GetItem(sa_idx, 0).GetText()
        sa_err_check_Comment = cur.execute("select cate,chek_comment from sa_er_cate where cate ='%s'" %sa_err_check)

        for row in sa_err_check_Comment:
        self.sa_er_question_ti.SetLabel(row[0])
        self.sa_er_question_te.SetLabel(row[1])


        model_name_string = row[0] 


        result_query_1 = cur.execute("Select symp from sac_er_ramp where cate='%s'" % model_name_string)


        list=[] 


        for row_test in result_query_1:

            list.append(row_test[0])

        self.cb.SetItems(list)


    def OnSelectComboBox(self,event):

        item = event.GetString()


        result_query_2 = cur.execute("Select symp, descrip, judgement,image from sac_er_ramp where symp='%s'" % item)

        for row in result_query_2:
            self.cas2_symp_text.SetLabel(row[0])
            self.cas2_descrip_text.SetLabel(row[1])

            imageno = row[3]


    # -- image box -> this is problem

    """
    erim = Image.open('./image/image_error_ramp/%s.webp' % imageno)
    erim.info.pop('background',None)
    erim.save('./image/image_error_ramp/%s.gif' % imageno,save_all=True, loop=0)
    anim = Animation('./image/image_error_ramp/%s.gif' % imageno)
    ctrl = AnimationCtrl(self.Panel_err_image, -1,anim, pos=(35,40))
    ctrl.Play()
    os.remove('./image/image_error_ramp/%s.gif' % imageno)            
    """




if __name__=="__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Post your code, not an interpretation of it.

Comment: Sorry Rolf of Saxony I am stupid....

Comment: Have you tried `print (event.GetString())` It will work. I suspect that your issue is probably with your sqlite3 selection or following code.

Answer (score 0):

The event parameter passed to the event handler function includes a `GetSelection` method which can be used to get the index of the item that was selected, and a `GetString` method to fetch the label of that item.

Comment: Thanks Robin (and really suprised you answer to my stupid question....) really thanks

Comment: from a above code at location A, I want to catch combobox's striing. of course use GetSelection, and GetString but result is always -1....   combobox bind with event  and event function comboboxevent can catch a combobox's string and selection but I want (if possible) get a value of combobox selection at location a is it possible?

Comment: Maybe it is fool question but i thought about this problem al least 2 weeks. (:-()